# Remove Border From The Last Child In Elementor Posts

Tags: css, css-selectors, elementor

I'd like to remove the border from the last post in all post widgets in Elementor.

I have set a custom class for all my post widgets `post-list` I have then added the custom CSS on the page level (as I want this rule globally)

```
.post-list:last-child {
    border: none !important;
}
```

However, this has not removed the border of the last post.

### HTML STRUCTURE

```
<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-1c04e94" data="1c04e94" dataElementType="column">
    <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-05e24aa elementor-grid-1 elementor-hidden-phone elementor-posts--thumbnail-none elementor-grid-tablet-1 post-list elementor-grid-mobile-1 elementor-widget elementor-widget-posts">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-posts-container elementor-posts elementor-posts--skin-classic elementor-grid">
                    <article class="elementor-post elementor-grid-item post-571 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-for-fun">
                    <div ...>
                    <article class="elementor-post elementor-grid-item post-571 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-for-fun">
                    <div ...>
                    <article class="elementor-post elementor-grid-item post-571 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-for-fun">
                    <div ...>
```

Comment: Using `:last-child` depends o the `html structure` ... and to have a look to the specifity (overwriting of css rules) of the CSS rules the CSS seting the borders is needed. So, to get help it would be helpful if you would provide some executable code including HTML/CSS structure to the element(s)

Comment: @Brebber updated the question with HTML structure of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after realizing I wasn't referencing the correct class.

```
.post-list
.elementor-grid article:last-child {
    border: none !important;
}
```